# Selenium webscraping issue, data not loading

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, row

I have an issue, I try scraping a website, what I'm scraping is a table and I get every element, row by row.

Where I have an issue is that an element seems to be loaded only if you scroll to it and let it stay in the field of view for a little while.

Here is the code I use to scrape the text of the element :

```
tspan_element = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "text > tspan")
row_data.append(tspan_element.text)
```

I would like some help to find a solution to load all of the element, because I manage to get the content of the first 2 row but not the rest.
If you want the website : https://ereferer.com
And the page I want to scrap : https://ereferer.com/bo/exchange-site-find

Comment: Site is behind a login. Post the HTML of that particular page (complete) -- use a service like Pastebin for that.

Comment: if you do a `print(driver.page_source)` -- does it look the same as in what you pasted? Are you in fact trying to obtain a dataframe from table with `id="quickPurchaseTable"`?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I did the command, and yes it seem to be the same, that I pasted. Also what I want to do is getting the content of the rows element by element to after convert it into a CSV file.

Comment: If you want I can past more of my code for you to understand.

Comment: That would help, yes. Also, again: are you trying to get data from table with id="quickPurchaseTable"?

Comment: Also I opened the html from the pastebin into an html beautifuller and it miss the content in the rows

Comment: And yes it's the content of quickPurshaseTable

Comment: That's fine: you can scroll the page down with Selenium, prior to reading that element content. Once you scroll the page down, or you zoom it out to 0.01, or you open a huge headless page -- all methods to load that data, then you can read that table directly with pandas.

Comment: For me I think the best case would be zooming out, because I need to stay some time on the element for it to spawn. I will try that

Comment: It tried zooming out and it didn't work I can't manage to get it to spawn. Even when I can see the whole page

Comment: Did you try clicking on the page, or using ActionChains to move the mouse to that table element? Did you try scrolling the page?

Comment: What is strange is that when I do it in my actual webbrowser and not the one from selenium it manage to load them, maybe because I have them in cache idk.

Comment: I can't manage to find how to scroll the page .

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, I simulate a scroll of the page. It work fine.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to solve the issue of element not loading if not in view is to simulate a scroll, I did that with a script.

```
scroll_script = """
        const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        const scrollStep = Math.floor(scrollHeight / 100);
        let scrollPosition = 0;
        function scrollToBottom() {
            if (scrollPosition < scrollHeight) {
                scrollPosition += scrollStep;
                window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
                setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 50);
            }
        }
        scrollToBottom();
        """
```

Then I did a `driver.execute_script(scroll_script)` to execute the script.
It will make you scroll slowly to the bottom of the page so every element have the time to generate itself.